# How to add Objective-c library manually to Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to add the Objective-c version of the [PINRemoteImage library](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage) to my project manually. Based on their [Github](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage) docs, I should:

> Download the latest tag and drag the Pod/Classes folder into your
> Xcode project. You must also manually link against PINCache.

So I downloaded the latest version from the given link, extracted it and got the following files in the folder[image]

Then copied the Classes folder into the Xcode project (checked the copy if needed option).
[image]
And when I run the app, I get the following error:
[image]

I understand it doesn't find the required file from the package, but can't figure out the issue. I also tried the same with the whole Source folder, but  didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your case it might help to change the include to #import "PINRemoteImage.h". Or you can add the path to the header to the HEADER SEARCH PATH setting in your Xcode project.

Comment: @jackdaimond tried that too, unfortunately in this case it just simply missing the .h file.

Comment: It says: ‘You must also manually link against PINCache’, and the error looks suspiciously similar to the one you’d get if you didn’t link. Does the library show up in the target settings?